# Why is the list contents generated incorrectly in my code?

Tags: python, list, function, tuples, return

it returns a list of length = 4 // e.g. `[8, 'Eight', 7, 'Seven']`

I was expecting a list of length = 2// e.g `[ (8, 'Eight'), (7, 'Seven') ]`

```
import random
choice_list =[(2, 'Two'), (8, 'Eight'), (3, 'Three'), (7, 'Seven')]
def dealer(cards_list_func):
    initial_cards = []
    for item in range(2):
        initial_cards += random.choice(cards_list_func)
    return initial_cards

new_list = dealer(choice_list)
```

Comment: Take a look at *random.sample*. With your current use of *random.choice* you could select the same 'card' twice and that may not be what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

random.sample greatly simplifies your code as follows:

```
import random
choice_list =[(2, 'Two'), (8, 'Eight'), (3, 'Three'), (7, 'Seven')]
def dealer(cards_list_func):
    return random.sample(cards_list_func, min(2, len(cards_list_func)))


new_list = dealer(choice_list)
print(new_list)
```

**Sample output:**

```
[(8, 'Eight'), (3, 'Three')]
```

**Note:**

In the original question, random.choice was being used in a loop (two iterations) which could lead to the same selection being made for each of the two choices. That may have been required in which case this is not a precise solution

Answer (score 2):

The `+=` operator on lists does an operation similar to `list.extend()`.
You want `list.append()`.

So just do:

```py
initial_cards.append(cards_list_func)
```

Comment: perfect!! appreciate it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with how you are adding the random choice to the final list of cards. Instead of using `+=`, you want to use `.append`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend) is a link to a post that might be helpful in understanding the difference between `.extend` and `.append`.

Here is an example of what you're looking for:

```
import random
choice_list =[(2, 'Two'), (8, 'Eight'), (3, 'Three'), (7, 'Seven')]
def dealer(cards_list_func):
    initial_cards = []
    for item in range(2):
        initial_cards.append(random.choice(cards_list_func))
    return initial_cards

new_list = dealer(choice_list)
new_list
> [(2, 'Two'), (3, 'Three')]
```